# Serve custom MIME types from Rails 3 Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, mime-types, ogg

I'm trying to serve an Opus audio file from rails.  I have the file in `vendor/assets/my_custom_folder_for_audio/file.opus`.  I can access the file by visiting `localhost:3000/assets/file.opus`.  But if I try to load the file as the src of an audio element, I get an error about the MIME type being `application/octet-stream` when it should be `audio/ogg`.  Rails has a file `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`, but that looks like it's meant for respond_to blocks, which you don't use for the asset pipeline.  Should the audio file just be in `public/`?  That still doesn't solve the MIME type issue.  Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working by making these changes:

`vendor/assets/my_custom_folder_for_audio/file.opus` -> `vendor/assets/audio/file.ogg`